# Can't flag comment

Tags: bug, android-app, comment-flags

[This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474988/if-bbb-c-infty-is-the-only-infinite-dimensional-hilbert-space-why-do-other#comment5163045_2474988) cannot be flagged, even when the other can.

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: E2312

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (4059386522)